# Only one view is displayed in Android

Tags: android, view, android-layout

I am new to Android. When i run this code, only one circle is displayed. If i remove view1, then view2 is displayed. but they are never displayed together!!! why is that? 
Any help would be appreciated.

thanks

```
package com.dots;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
public class Dots1Activity extends Activity
{
    private static final String TAG = "DotsActivity";
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        TextView label = new TextView(this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
             LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        label.setText("Click the circle!");
        CustomDrawableView view1 = new CustomDrawableView(this, 100, 100, 50, Color.RED);
        CustomDrawableView view2 = new CustomDrawableView(this, 200, 200, 25, Color.GREEN);
        CustomDrawableView view3 = new CustomDrawableView(this, 300, 300, 10, Color.WHITE);
        ll.addView(label, layoutParams);
        ll.addView(view1, layoutParams);
        ll.addView(view2, layoutParams);
        ll.addView(view3, layoutParams);
        setContentView(ll);
    }

}

 class CustomDrawableView extends View implements OnClickListener{
     private Context context;
    private int x, y, radius, color;
    public CustomDrawableView(Context context, int x, int y, int radius, int color) {
        super(context);
        this.context = context;
        this.x = x;
        this.y =y;
        this.radius = radius;
        this.color = color;
        setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) 
    {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        this.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
        Paint paint = new Paint (Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        paint.setColor(color);
        canvas.drawCircle(x, y, radius, paint);

    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(this.context, 
                x+"-"+y+"-"+radius, 
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
```

They are put next to each other. You can't see them, because your display isn't width naught. Put them in a [HorizontalScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html) or make them aper `VERTICAL`.

---

I'm not sure if this takes effect here, but i found this on the [Android Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#Drawing):

> Note that the framework will not draw
>   views that are not in the invalid
>   region. To force a view to draw, call
>   invalidate().

<strike>Try if this solves your problem (for the moment I guess).</strike>

---

### About your Code

Something i noticed: The implemented interface for the `onClickListener` is `View.OnClickListener`:

```
class CustomDrawableView extends View implements View.OnClickListener{ [...] }
```

### How to solve the Problem

I looked around on the Android Docs and found [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html#custom). They mantioned the method [onMeasure()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onMeasure%28int,%20int%29), which:

> Measure the view and its content to
>   determine the measured width and the
>   measured height.

So I added it to your custom `CustomDrawableView`-class. Unfortuandly, you can't pass the `super.onMeasure()`-method simple integers, you'll need to decode them first, using the [View.MeasureSpec](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.MeasureSpec.html)-class:

```
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec){
        super.onMeasure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(100, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
                View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(100, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
    }
```

In the Example, I set both width and height to 100px. Also, I did some other improvements on your code:

#### Dots1Activity-class

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Dots1Activity extends Activity
{
    private static final String TAG = "DotsActivity";
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        TextView label = new TextView(this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
             LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        label.setText("Click the circle!");
        CustomDrawableView view1 = new CustomDrawableView(this, 50, 50, 50, Color.RED);
        CustomDrawableView view2 = new CustomDrawableView(this, 75, 75, 25, Color.GREEN);
        CustomDrawableView view3 = new CustomDrawableView(this, 85, 85, 10, Color.WHITE);
        ll.addView(label, layoutParams);
        ll.addView(view1, layoutParams);
        ll.addView(view2, layoutParams);
        ll.addView(view3, layoutParams);
        setContentView(ll);
    }

}
```

#### CustomDrawableView-class

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

class CustomDrawableView extends View implements View.OnClickListener{
     private Context context;
    private int x, y, radius, color;
    public CustomDrawableView(Context context, int x, int y, int radius, int color) {
        super(context);
        this.context = context;
        this.x = x;
        this.y =y;
        this.radius = radius;
        this.color = color;
        setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) 
    {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        paint.setColor(color);
        canvas.drawCircle(x, y, radius, paint);
    }

    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec){
        super.onMeasure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(100, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
                View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(100, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(this.context, 
                x+"-"+y+"-"+radius, 
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
    }
}
```

This code compiles, shows all the circles and the onClick-Event works, too.

Although I have to say it was a bit of a challenge and I'm grateful for it.

Comment: thanks for your reply.
I will try it.
but one thing i cant understand, every shape's position is different on the screen and they do not "overlap" when i display them individually. So why is the width of the screen a problem?

Comment: does not work.
It is as if the first CustomDrawableView object (view1) is taking all the screen apart the label.
I see the label and view1 on a grey background. Whereever i click , even outside of view1 ,(except on the label) i see the Toast which displays the description of view1 only

What i am doing wrong here?

Comment: As I'm a huge fan of the XML-way to do this, I've never ran into this problem before. The `CustomDrawableView`-class extends `View`, I guess? Can you post the code of this class, too?

Comment: thanks for your reply.
Yes it does extend View.
I have posted the class, just scroll the code.

I dont think i will do it the xml way  as i will have many CustomDrawableView objects, created dynamically, on the screen.

Comment: You do realize that the given X- and Y-coordinates are seen from your View's upper left corner, not from the Activity's ? What happens if you set all X- and Y-coordinates to `0`?

Comment: I thought it was from the screen!
When i put every X and Y to 0, i can see only part of the RED dot (because its radius is 50) but i dont see the other dots.
Also i have inserted a log into the onDraw() function of CustomDrawableView  class, but i see only 1 log instead of 3 !!!

Comment: I have tried inserting the invalidate() in the onDraw() of the class CustomDrawableView, no success. The Toast keep appearing and disappearing, like an infinite loop, and i can only see the red circle, not the others.

I have also tried, ll.invalidate() (the LinearLayout obj), but is same as before.

Comment: Thanks alot, i am grateful to you.
It works.

But i have another question. Why is it necessary to declare another Context object in my CustomDrawableView, which already has a Context from the superclass View?

Comment: You need the Context to initialize the View (`super(context);`). For some other function-calls, a Context is also required. If you don't need the Context after calling the superclass's constructor, you don't need to keep it...

Comment: hmmm ok
one last thing (i just hope it is the last!). I have removed the Label and the set radius of the 3 circles to 100. Why they are cut? please see the [image](http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=v4cup5&s=7). It is as if the layout is not taking the whole screen.

thanks

Comment: If you set the radius of the higher, you'll need to set the values in the `onMessure`-method higher, too. In my code, I sat them to a constant value of 100px. That's why your circle isn't fully showing.

Comment: Yes i did update the onMeasure. the new radius is 50, and in the onMeasure, i set it to 100.
even for radius=25, onMeasure=100, it does not make any difference in terms on the circles not completely displayed.

Comment: It looks to me like the other two circles are not shown because of your chosen X- and Y-coordinate. The X-Y coordinates define the middle-point of the circle you're drawing. So if your Radius is 50 you should set them to the half (e.g. `X=25`, `Y=25`).

Comment: i dont think this is the problem. If you see the image, you will see that the last circle is cut from its right and bottom. there is no circle on its right to overlap it.

Comment: Thats not my point. All your Views are put underneath each others (`LinearLayout`, `VORIZONTAL`). The Problem is, the View only shows 100x100px. Your circle has an x- and y-coordinate which indicates where the circles middle-point is and a radius which indicates it's size. You want to draw a bigger circle or use bigger x- or y-coordinates, you'll need to change the shown Views size to something bigger.

Comment: What have you tried? Dude, please add your code to the original post or create a new one.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have created a new thread here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6376462/custom-view-not-displayed-well-in-android

Comment: hmm, now i see your pt, after the answer in the other thread. I did not quite understand .

thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

change the orientation of you layout to vertical like this :

```
ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
```