# custom View not displayed well in android

Tags: android, view, custom-view

My custom view does not display entirely. Please see my screenshot:

[image]

And the source code

```
package com.dots;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Dots1Activity extends Activity
{
    private static final String TAG = "DotsActivity";
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);          


        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
             LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        CustomDrawableView view1 = new CustomDrawableView(this, 50, 50, Constants.DOTS_RADIUS, Constants.DOTS_COLOR);
        CustomDrawableView view2 = new CustomDrawableView(this, 150, 150, Constants.DOTS_RADIUS, Constants.DOTS_COLOR);
        CustomDrawableView view3 = new CustomDrawableView(this, 300, 300, Constants.DOTS_RADIUS, Constants.DOTS_COLOR);
        ll.addView(view1, layoutParams);
        ll.addView(view2, layoutParams);
        ll.addView(view3, layoutParams);
        setContentView(ll);
    }

}

class CustomDrawableView extends View implements View.OnClickListener{
    private Context context;
   private int x, y, radius, color;
   public CustomDrawableView(Context context, int x, int y, int radius, int color) {
       super(context);
       this.context = context;
       this.x = x;
       this.y =y;
       this.radius = radius;
       this.color = color;
       setOnClickListener(this);
   }

   protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) 
   {
       super.onDraw(canvas);
       Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
       paint.setColor(color);
       canvas.drawCircle(x, y, radius, paint);
   }

   protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec){
       super.onMeasure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(Constants.DOTS_RADIUS*2, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
               View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(Constants.DOTS_RADIUS*2, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
   }

   public void onClick(View v) {
       Toast.makeText(this.context, 
               x+"-"+y+"-"+radius, 
               Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
   }
}



public interface Constants 
{
    public static final int DOTS_RADIUS = 50;
    public static final int DOTS_COLOR = Color.GREEN;
    public static final int NUM_DOTS_ROWS = 5;
    public static final int NUM_DOTS_COLS = 5;
    public static final int WIDTH_BETWEEN_DOTS = 100;
    public static final int HEIGHT_BETWEEN_DOTS = 100;


}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. What is the problem and what are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making the assumption that you don't want the clipping you see in your screenshot. Your problem is that the values you return in onMeasure don't account for your x, y offsets:

```
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec){
    super.onMeasure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(Constants.DOTS_RADIUS*2 + x, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
           View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(Constants.DOTS_RADIUS*2 + y, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
}
```

Comment: thanks guys, this works!
but one thing I dont undersand, isnt the x,y cordinates relative to the left top corner of the screen? so why i have to add the offsets?

Comment: It's relative to the view. If this works for you, you should accept the answer.

Comment: ok it makes some sense now, i will have to play a little more to understand it better

thanks alot everyone for your help. really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you want to Achieve? if you want to be fullscreen then use the FILL_PARENT flag instead of WRAP_CONTENT at least for the width of your view. also for the height there is a weight parameter that might help even the height of your view. but since its a custom drawing i cant help you further if there are any adjustments needed in your view code. you have to figure that out for yourself.

Comment: I want to add like a grid of dots
i will have like 5 rows and 5 columns
and each rows and and columns will contains like 5 dots, so 25 dots in all, spread over the screen
but when i add 3 dots, the last dot is cut, and when i add more, it is like the dots are overlapping, 
they do not spread over the whole of the screen, instead they are in the small "rectangle". i can not add anything more than the rectangle

Answer (score 0):

The radius of each of your "dots" is identical, and this directly translates into the answer you return in onMeasure(). You're changing the x and y location of the center, getting further from the actual View canvas.